# Queue input is backward in time

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

Someday i got this error(
Queue input is backward in time
)
Now i develop app for screen recording, and i have to catch this error for future testing.
How can i catch/get this error again?
Which command i have to use in order to do that?

I tried to use command below:

```
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M -framerate 30 -draw_mouse 1 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Stereo mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -filter_complex "[0]format=yuv420p[v];[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] -movflags +faststart recording.mp4
```

I just removed rtbufsize, thread_queue_size, probesize parameters, and hoped that i will catch this error(Queue input is backward in time), but unfortunately, i haven't caught this error.